# use koa-router redircet filed

Tags: node.js, redirect, koa, koa-router

I do a post ajax request to node with koa-router ,  and I want to redirect '/' ,but url didn`t change . this is my code :

```
router.post('/action',function *(next){
     //some action
     this.redirect('/');
});
```

my wish is  '/login' = > '/' ,but  url didn`t change , '/login' => '/login' .
[this is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77JLX.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can't redirect a browser via an ajax response. The browser executes ajax requests asynchronously and a `Location: ...` header in an ajax response will *not* change the browser URL. The ajax request itself is being redirected to the `/` url, but not your current browser window.

Answer (score 0):

@jbielick is on the right path: I cannot think on any scenario that makes sense to do a redirection in an ajax request.

Anyway, forgetting the ajax issue. there's an easier way to do redirections with koa-router

Simply use:

```js
 
  router.redirect('/action', '/');
```